# Customize Admin Section

Tags: customization, admin

I am custimizing WordPress in order to use it as CMS. This CMS system will have multiple user accounts at different levels of previlidges and autherization. Now, when it comes to using the admin section, I would like to make sure the users unaware that the system they are using is based on WordPress (there are many reasons for this decision, one of them is security by ambiguity).

In any case, now, I need to customize the admin section. I have two solutions in my mind:

1. Customize the existing admin section.
2. Create new user admin pages, and write new admin functionality in those pages.

Which solution is more accurate? Why? And more importantly, where can I find documentation to do this? I could not find much on the web to suppport either approach.

Thanks.

Comment: I'll offer my tuppence, Don't do it. I'm currently writing such a plugin, to bring the relevant interface to the front, and it's a major headache. Most of the Wordpress internals is still geared towards a single user blog structure. The per-user additions are just "workarounds". IMO, the whole admin area could do with a rewrite, based on classes not functions, and force plugin developers to adopt the changes rather than trying to leave in support for them.

Comment: if you rewrite significant portions of the admin interface in the name of security, you'll just potentially introduce new security issues with a codebase not vetted by thousands of users and hundreds of developers.

Comment: So should I abandon WordPress altogether and develop my own infra structure instead because I have multiple users?

Comment: I have often thought the same but the benefits outweigh the disadvantages. With your own system you would have to literally rewrite everything including all those plugins.

Comment: @Waldermort - I think I am leaning towards solutions 2 mentoined above. I will have develop new admin pages for each user group, and add functionality as I see fit.